# Get ENV variable value into form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am looking to pass the params from a post request into my controller so that i can save the information, I am using stripe and would like to pass the email address that someone has provided via stripes **Stripe::Customer.create** method

```
 customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
   :email => 'example@stripe.com',
   :card  => params[:stripeToken]
 )
```

In my form i have

```
<%= form_tag donations_path do %>
 <%= text_field_tag :email, :placeholder => "Email Address", :data => {:stripe => 'email' }%>
```

So to get the email address supplied by the user into the customer object I can do

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
   :email => params[:email],
   :card  => params[:stripeToken]
 )
```

but how do i set the :stripeToken in my form, its stored in an ENV variable at the moment, do i use a hidden_field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that token is in your ENV, you don't have to display it in form, just get it in controller when you need it.